# return object values with const 1 liner

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

So here's an example of some code, using an array of objects, for simple arbitrary data.

const function at the bottom to find my flight number represented as `flightNu`

```
var flights = [{
        "id": 1234,
        "airline": "Delta",
        "depart": "11/23/2016 10:25 AM",
        "arrive": "11/23/2016 11:35 AM",
        "from": "TPA",
        "to": "MEM"
    }, {
        "id": 4321,
        "airline": "AA",
        "depart": "11/23/2016 12:25 PM",
        "arrive": "11/23/2016 2:35 PM",
        "from": "DWF",
        "to": "SEA"
    }]

var flightNu = 4321; 

const flightDetails = (a) => 
a.map(f => (f.id == flightNu) ? f : null )


console.log(flightDetails(flights))
```

So my question lies with properly defining this const function

```
const flightDetails = (a) => 
a.map(f => (f.id == flightNu) ? f : null )
```

This is returning `[null, Object]`
Object is the correct one, with flightNu.
Found it, cool, but let's say I add 100 objects, that'd be 99 nulls returned. That's 99 problems but a Matching Flight Number ain't one. (sorry)

Can someone shed some light on a good way to use this? Maybe I shouldn't be using ternary operator. If I could return the proper `f[index]` that'd be great.

## Preferably without assigning Object to another variable

```
var MatchingFlight;

const flightDetails = (a) => 
 a.map(f => {
     if (f.id === flightNu){
              MatchingFlight = f;
     }
 }) ? MatchingFlight : null   //returns Object {}  close but meh
```

This snippet works in the proposed goal sense, but defining MatchingFlight outside of scope doesn't seem right for `const`.

Comment: If you want the first match, use `.find()` instead of `.map()`.

Comment: instead of `map` use `filter`.

Comment: @torazaburo well i added the update for one scenario that works, There's other snippets that work, but the true answer is SLaks with 3 possible methods, which isn't a snippet, so I just wanted to update with a possible snippet for completeness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` in JavaScript which returns the elements that match the filter something like this

```
const flightDetails = (a) => 
a.filter(f => (f.id == flightNu))
```

Comment: I played around with filter and came back with same thing pretty much except I didn't use ternary operator this time. Should I or does it matter?

Comment: It depends, sometimes if object is undefined then we can use ternary operator because if it fails we are assigning it to null. Otherwise it's not necessary to use ternary operator. Hope this helps. Answered your question?

Answer (score 4):

`map()` transforms every element to something else.
That's not what you want.

You want `filter()` (which returns only matching elements) or `find()` (which returns the first match), not `map()`.

Comment: `find()` would be good in certain cases, but since `filter()` returns an array and let's say mutliple flight numbers are found for arguments sake, then that works pretty well in this case.